# Removing URL's from the XML sitemap

Tags: xml, sitemap

I have an XML site map where some URLs don't work (they pages have been moved and are now using different URLs) is it advisable to remove these URLs from the XML site map and generate a new one. Apparently Google doesn't see any problem with that and should not index them anyway but what is the best practice on that?

Comment: change them by the new one, or generate new one

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your old URLs redirect and then update your XML sitemap with your new URLs